# parsing complex csv file

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a CSV file which maps each country to some value, but the problem is that it's not well formed, it's header has repetitive pattern: Countries, Amount, Countries, Amount, ... (here Amounts measure different things, for example suicide rate, alcohol consumption etc., note that for some countries data is missing), please see input DataFrame: `df_in`.

I would like to get countries as index and those 'Amounts' as columns, please see output DataFrame, `df_out`

```
df_in = pd.read_csv('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/40513206/input.csv', sep = ';', header = 0, index_col = None,
             na_values = [''], mangle_dupe_cols = False)

df_out = pd.read_csv('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/40513206/output.csv', sep = ';', header = 0, index_col = None,
             na_values = [''], mangle_dupe_cols = False)
```

I was thinking that at first I get all unique countries from input (make it an index of new empty DataFrame, for example

```
col_pat = df_in.columns[df_in.columns.to_series().str.contains('Countries')]
cntry = df_in.ix[:, col_pat]
un_elm = pd.Series(map(str, pd.unique(cntry.values.ravel())))
countries = un_elm[un_elm != 'nan']
```

then start splitting main DataFrame (Counrtries as index and Amount as column) and joining it cumulatively to empty DataFrame.
Any other ideas, thanks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first use .ix to select columns based on location

```
df_in = pd.read_csv('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/40513206/input.csv', sep = ';',      header = 0, index_col = None,
         na_values = [''], mangle_dupe_cols = False)

df1 = df_in.ix[:,:2].dropna().set_index('Countries1')
df2 = df_in.ix[:,2:4].dropna().set_index('Countries2')
df3 = df_in.ix[:,4:].dropna().set_index('Countries3')
```

then concatenate on axis 1 :

```
pd.concat([df1,df2,df3], axis=1)


               Amount  Amount  Amount
Austria           NaN       5     NaN
Denmark             6     NaN     NaN
France              3     NaN     NaN
Ireland           NaN     NaN       6
Norway            NaN       2     NaN
Russia            NaN     NaN       5
Slovenia          NaN     NaN       4
Spain             NaN       3       3
Sweden              5       1       2
Switzerland         4       4     NaN
U.K.                1     NaN     NaN
United States       2     NaN       1
```